# append data from angularjs scope in div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm getting dynamic data from ajax call which I want to append to a div container with the results from the call but the div is not rendered for some reason.

This is what I have, in the controller:

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/Search/SearchParts',
   params: { id: id, packageid: $scope.packageid, searchterm: item.SearchValue }
}).success(function (data) {
      $scope.searchresults = data;
});
```

And then in the html I have this:

```
<modal title="Search for parts" visible="showSearchForm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                Enter Search Criteria:
                <input type="text" ng-model="item.SearchValue" 
                    class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button ng-click="searchPart(item)" 
                     class="btn btn-success pull-right">Search Part</button>
                <input type="hidden" 
                     ng-model="$scope.packageid" 
                     id="hfVehiclePackageIdSearchPart"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="result in $scope.searchresults">
                <label>{{result.linecode}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</modal>
```

The last div which has ng-repeat with the data is not being rendered.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's inside the `$scope.searchresults` ? can you provide the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `$scope` in you template files you should use like

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="result in searchresults"><!-- remove $scope -->
```

You have another line here also

```
<input type="hidden" 
     ng-model="packageid" <!-- remove $scope -->
     id="hfVehiclePackageIdSearchPart" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reference $scope in your html.

You can use the models directly like ng-repeat="result in results".